# Reading values from string in C++

Tags: c++, string

I am making a program that reads a user input of a number equation in text, for example:(thirty_three + forty_two). 
The program needs to be able to read inputs up to 999 and output up to 999.
My code to output numbers up to 999 works fine

```
string* write_value(int n, string* first) {
int th = (n % 10000) / 1000;
int h = (n % 1000) / 100;
int t = (n % 100) / 10;
int u = (n % 10);

if (th > 0) {
    *first++ = units[h] + "_thousand";
}

if (h > 0) {
    *first++ = units[h] + "_hundred";
}

if (t == 1) { // deal with the pesky teens
    t -= 1;
    u += 10;
}

if (t > 0) {
    *first++ = tens[t];
}

if (u > 0) {
    *first++ = units[u];
}

return first;
}
```

But my read_value function doesnt accept the "hundreds" text as an input and skips over it. How would i go about implementing this into my read_value function?

```
string* read_digit(int& value, string* first, string* last, string* digits, int count) {
if (first < last) {
    for (int i = 1; i < count; ++i) {
        if (*first == digits[i]) {
            value = i;
            return first + 1;
        }
    }
}
return first;
}

int read_value(string* first, string* last) {
int th = 0;
int h = 0;
int t = 0;
int u = 0;

first = read_digit(t, first, last, tens, 10);
first = read_digit(u, first, last, units, 20);
first = read_digit(h, first, last, units, 10);
first = read_digit(th, first, last, units, 10);

return (th * 1000) + (h * 100) + (t * 10) + u;
}


int Wordnum::read_number(string n) {
string words[20];     // enough for up to 999,999,999
string* last = split(n, words, '_');

if (last == words || words[0] == "zero") {
    return 0;
}
else if (words[0] == "negative") {
    return -read_value(words + 1, last);
}
else {
    return read_value(words, last);
}
}
```

Comment: post what output are you getting and what you expect? Also try to highlight the specific code in which you are facing the problem. Dont just post the whole code

Comment: Oh sorry I'm new to this :) Ah yeah so if i input let's say: twenty_five * four i get "one_hundred" as the output but if i input: one_hundred_two + three i get four as the output.

Comment: you get output as 'four' or 'five'?

Comment: The site where one can get answers in few seconds, there you haven't got    since last 16 hours. Basically either code should be complete so that one can understand the situation or it should be very specific to the problem you are facing(which is preferred over the former).